# Failure delivering result ResultInfo android

Tags: android, android-camera, runtime-error

My app is when user click take a photo button,it will save a picture in external storage.in this face it's working when i check in my folder in device.But I don't understand why My intent equal null ,while i putExtra into intent.And

this is my code

```
private void captureImage(){
    //check Is device support a camera??
    isDeviceSupportCamera();
    if(isDeviceSupportCamera() == true){
        //intent to camera process
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //สร้างไฟล์ใหม่มาลองรับ รูปที่ถูกถ่าย ไปยัง picDirectory
        imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path,
                    "img_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

        startActivityForResult(intent, imageCode);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Your device is not supprot feature camera");
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == imageCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){



            //add imageFile to array File
            fileCapture.add(imageFile);
            //set adapter
            gridView.setAdapter(new gridviewAdapter(context, fileCapture));


    }else if(requestCode == imageCode && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user cancle a image capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and this is logcat error

```
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 09:37:34.625: E/AndroidRuntime(24772): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/14298 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.newlookrecipe/com.example.newlookrecipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException{com.example.newlookrecipe/com.example.newlookrecipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at com.example.newlookrecipe.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:96)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
02-07 00:48:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(18495):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source:

```
/**
 * Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera application
 * capture an image and return it.
 * <p>
 * The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written.
 * If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap
 * object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image.
 * If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri
 * value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.
 * @see #EXTRA_OUTPUT
 */
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.ACTIVITY_INTENT_ACTION)
public final static String ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE = "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE";
```

Notice **If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present**.

Since you include `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri.fromFile(imageFile));`, you are expressing an `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` with the purpose of saving the captured image to the file system.  Android knows that you know the location of the image, so it won't bother delivering back the thumbnail image that it would provide if you launched the `Intent` without specify this extra.  Since it's not sending back data, your `Intent` object will be null.

If you want a thumbnail image, or to add the image to an image view, you can just use the `Uri` that you provided to the `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you Submersed.if i want a thumbnail image capture i can get it from imageFile.getAbsolutePath();.now i delete this line from code."intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri.fromFile(imageFile));",But it's still error.Can you check it again please.

Comment: So, from looking at the code you've provided, it doesn't look like you are even accessing the Intent object in onActivityResult.  Are you sure that the intent object being null is the problem, or is it your "fileCapture" or "gridView"?

Comment: Also, it might help to follow the training docs:  http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html a

Comment: Thank you , i try code for long . now it is not error